# Confused by a very simple if / else statement in perl

Tags: perl, boolean, if-statement

```
print "content-type: text/html \n\n";   #The header
$file = "newtext.txt";
if (unlink($file) == 0) {
    print "File deleted successfully.";
} else {
    print "File was not deleted.";
}
```

This is some code I picked up from tizag.  The part I don't understand is that the bool value for true is 1, and false is 0.  So why is it when I successfully delete the file I'm checking to see if it returns a 0?

Comment: The lesson here: When in doubt, check perldoc. [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) was my best friend while learning, and still is, as it happens.

Comment: or at the command line `perldoc -f unlink`

Comment: Note to SO Perl regulars: this is the second time that [tizag](http://www.tizag.com/perlT/) attracted attention in an aggravating way. Until someone can go through the site with a fine comb and point out all the errors and submit for correction, I have shitlisted this resource and recommend you do so, too.

Answer (score 6):

That seems like a mistake.. from [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html):

> Deletes a list of files. On success,
>   it returns the number of files it
>   successfully deleted. On failure, it
>   returns false and sets $! (errno):

If the return value is 0, you deleted 0 files.

The correct way to write it would be:

```
if (unlink($file)) { print "Success!" }
else { print "Unlink failed: $!" }
```

Comment: And the more idiomatic `unlink $file or die "unlink $file failed: $!"`.  Use autodie to handle this for you.  It ships with 5.10.1.  http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?autodie

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think that's a bug. From the [perldoc for unlink](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html):

> On success, it returns the number of files it successfully deleted. On failure, it returns false and sets $! (errno)

Probably a shell programming on autopilot.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet can simply be wrong, cause [`unlink`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) returns the number of files successfully deleted.

Answer (score 0):

OK, nevermind my first response. This is from the perldoc for unlink:

> Deletes a list of files. On success, it returns the number of files it successfully deleted. On failure, it returns false and sets $! (errno)

Proof that there is no such thing as a standard. Also proof that whomever wrote that code, unfortunately has a bug. Personally I would have expected 0 to mean success. If you look at the C syscall `unlink`, zero means success. Utter madness, I tell you.

Comment: this allows for the more readable version `if (unlink('file')) { print "success" } else {print "failed"}`, no its not the C equivalent, but Perl is not C, this is a common Perl idiom.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? I do believe my answer is EXACTLY the same as everyone else.

Comment: Aside from the whole "Well C does it this way so perl should too..." bit you mean. Scripting languages are better when they're not a thin veneer calling C functions; then you don't send up with messes like php's mysql_real_escape_string() leaking out into libraries.

Comment: Perhaps they shouldn't call it unlink then?